# Convert Facebook Friendlist to a C# list in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a class `Friend` as below:

```
public class Friend:Java.Lang.Object
    {
        private string uid, name;


        public void setuid(String uid) {
            this.uid = uid;
        }
        public String getUid() {
            return this.uid;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        //public Bitmap pic_square;
    }
```

Now I used `FQL` and get result and friend list of the logged in user as below:

```
IList<object> data = (IList<object>)result["data"];
```

I get list containing object of friend.(uid and name). Now I am trying to parse it using a `foreach` loop as below with no success.

//I tried both IList and List neither worked.

```
    List<object> friendlist = new List<object>();

                                foreach (IDictionary<string, object> friend in data){
                                    Friend myfriend = new Friend();
                                    myfriend.setName((string)friend["name"]);
                                    myfriend.setuid ((string)friend["uid"]);

                                    //code breakes on below line.
                                    friendlist.Add(myfriend);
                                    myfriend.Dispose();
                            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "break" mean?  Do you get an error message or exception?  I why are you calling Dispose on the object that you just added to your collection?

Comment: Yes, Xamarin studio not showing any error. Code just stops debugging further.
And i am disposing the object(just for sake of being theoretically correct) as it will be creating for every iteration, the code even can not reach there.

Comment: Is Disposing an object that you are still using theoretically correct? Without error information, it is really tough to help you out. Maybe wrap it in a try / catch block to capture the error?

Comment: Thanks Scott , I have added try-catch and the problem is "uid". I am unable to set uid and its breaking my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it later. Key `uid` was not found, although it was in json that I get from `FQL` for friendlist. I changed it to Graph API and its working perfect.